# Simple rectifier circuit fails under load

Tags: rectifier, electrolytic-capacitor

I have a problem with a simple rectifier circuit that is designed to drive a DC motor. The motor is part of a ripple tank for a high school physics lab.

The input to the circuit is 12 VAC from a bench supply that appears to be good. This goes through a simple rectifier consisting of 2 diodes. There is a smoothing capacitor (1 µF, 450 V electrolytic) and what I assume is a voltage regulator, but I can't see any identifying markings.

This feeds into a potentiometer before going to the output. The diodes have been tested in-circuit using a DMM in diode mode and seem OK. The potentiometer also checked out OK when tested.

The voltage output varies from 0-9 V with no load on the output but crashes as soon as any load is applied. I had to use a light bulb as the load because the DC motor terminals are corroded beyond worthwhile repair.

Is it reasonable to assume that the capacitor has failed?

EDIT: I have added a photo of the "rectifier" and the motor terminals, I will need to take the unit apart again to draw a circuit diagram but the only thing missing from the picture is the diodes, a 1.5 kΩ input resistor and a 17 kΩ output resistor.

EDIT 2: I've identified the mystery device as a 2SD509 transistor and tried to draw a circuit diagram.

[image: ripple mechanism]

[image: tank assembly]

[image: front panel]

[image: reverse of panel]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Would you be able to draw up a schematic? Powering anything through a pot, unless it’s a very high power low resistance type, isn’t going to work well. Also 1uf is not sufficient input capacitance to power a motor or lightbulb.

Comment: Some photos of the circuit (including the 'what I assume is a voltage regulator') might help too.

Comment: JamieP, we'd like to help. Ripple tanks in HS physics labs are important to have working right. But it appears that their may be multiple problems to resolve. Not only corrosion on the motor itself. I think @BruceAbbott 's point about photos is likely going to be pretty important to see. A schematic as Bryan suggests would be wonderful. But it may be simple enough that seeing the photos could get us there. Can you arrange for some good photos to be taken?

Comment: What is the black component in the middle of the first picture? Can you tell us the markings on it?

Comment: The circuit can't power a load. It is unknown how much the motor or lamp needs, but 12VAC rectified with two diode drops is about 15V, and even a short circuit will be limited via the 1.5k resistor to 10mA. Why or how is this circuit expected to power a load?

Comment: I put the wrong part number for the transistor. it's actually a D2059 which is a power transistor?

Comment: That is a terrible regulator circuit. Much better can be made easily. || If you power the motor from the "DC" via the 1.5 K resistor but with the transistor collector disconnected, does the motor run? It seems unlikely that the 1st resistor is 1.5K unless the motor draws only milliwatts. Can you measure the resistor value and pot resistance?

Comment: The 1st resistor is brown-gray-red so actually 1.8 k-ohm. The pot measured at 100k-ohm.

Comment: It's really cheaply put together as well as being a terrible circuit.  I was just asked to "get it working",  I definitely need a new motor because the terminals are corroded beyond salvage so I can't even try that yet,

Comment: There’s no chance the motor is actually a voice coil actuator, or the 120hz ripple this circuit will create is actually what causes the wave action?

Comment: @Bryan.  Thanks for your comment.  The answer is that I don't know. My electronics background was in PCB faultfinding in the test equipment space,  Even then I've been out of the game for nearly 15 years teaching ESL. So, I'm very rusty,  What difference would it make to the loading of the circuit between a motor and a voice call actuator?

Comment: @JamieP Maybe it would just be better if you scrapped the whole thing and just told us what you'd like to achieve? Provide us a diagram of the ripple tank and the system that generates the ripples. Let us work out the details for the circuit to build. Start with the physical basics. If we know what that is, the rest can readily follow from there. This isn't rocket science. But I think you need to scrap what you have (circuit-wise) and figure on creating something new and better, for now. Just an opinion. Maybe we can help out. But we need details.

Comment: I just want to get the thing working. It is obviously a really cheaply made piece of junk and I have basic;ally zero budget to fix it.

Comment: I've added some new photos and removed others,

Comment: This WAS done by someone who apparently didn't know the basics of electronics. The first clue are two diodes where the second one is pointless. You could short either one and you would get the same functionality with less voltage drop. The answer by Bryan contains a workable schematic  - yours wouldn't work.

Comment: How about replacing it with just a variable DC power supply? Or do you need the 50 Hz ripple somehow?

Comment: The circuit you've drawn is... bizarre, to say the least. I'd be inclined to just replace the whole thing.

Comment: @JamieP Okay. That's a +1 addition of pictures!! Thanks! If someone can't help you with this, then we should just go away and find other work. You've done a brilliant job of posing the problem. Thanks again and nice job! I'm impressed and I hope some time is seriously applied to directly help you here.

Answer (score 1):

The following schematic may be closer to the requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new photos I have created a different schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdWnf7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(I guessed at the potentiometer resistance)

I  would encourage you to verify that this is correct, and as to why it doesnt work, my first suspect would be the potentiometer: they dont like... existence, let alone water - the wiper may no longer be making contact with the track. Diagnosis will require some basic multimeter skills, and a multimeter.

Also your transistor model number is probably incorrect as I get different package transistors when I search that part.

Comment: The R2 is 18k, as there isn't a 17k value and the second band color is clearly gray (8). R1 is 1k8.

Comment: I have managed to get confirmation that the motor is a Mabuchi Eg - 530ad - 2 F Dc motor.  I have ordered a replacement online and will put things on hold for now until I get that.    Thanks for everyone's help so far.

Comment: @EdinFifić noted and corrected, thanks.

Comment: @JamieP I agree with this circuit diagram - it's the same as what I arrived at "by inspection". Try connecting the transistor base (connects to pot wiper) to the R2/R1 junction. Motor should run at near full speed. If motor does not run at all try shorting out C and E on Q1 (connects top of load to top of R1. If motor does not run it is dead or a wire is broken - perhaps between R2 bottom and D2 OR D1 otr D2 is dead. || **One at a time** short out D1 and then D2

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bryan's circuit diagram - it's the same as what I arrived at "by inspection".

Try connecting the transistor base (connects to pot wiper) to the R2/R1 junction. Motor should run at near full speed.

If motor does not run at all try shorting out C and E on Q1 (connects top of load to top of R1. If motor does not run it is dead or a wire is broken - perhaps between R2 bottom and D2 OR D1 otr D2 is dead.

To test D1 and D2, **One at a time** short out D1 and then D2

Motor connected across C1 should run.